# Light to turn on for every second switching

Tags: electrical

I have a very modifiable simple fixture with two E14 sockets. I want to modify the wiring of one so that it only gets current when the switch is turned on an even number of times. I will put a strong LED bulb in this socket, and a weaker in the other.

Is there a simple, inexpensive and small way to achieve this?

---

Dimmable switches and dimmable LEDs are very expensive here.
I cannot replace the wiring between the switch and the fixture without serious masonry, this is a 50 years old concrete house. The fixture is not even grounded.

Comment: add a second switch

Comment: you can have a fun afternoon playing with latching and momentary relays: if i understand, 1 regular and 1 latching relay will do what you want. the regular relay self-disconnects (that is the coils power lead goes through it's COM+NC), to create a pulse with each power _on_. that pulse switches the latcher (via NO). it does nothing upon _off_, so it takes 2 _on_ to cycle the latching relay, which controls the "big light"

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer - no. At least none that I am aware of. You would need a logic loop that would keep track of the number of attempts.

Closest inexpensive method would be to purchase a three way lamp switch which would be off- on lamp1 - on lamp1 and lamp2-off.

Other than that good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be two bulbs? If not, Philips sells a series of LED bulbs which dim between high-medium-nightlight simply by flicking the switch on and off. I don't know what the availability is in your country, but it seems to be available in the UK.

For US readers, the bulb is Model 464883 for 2700 K and 464909 for 5000 K. I can't find the product on Philips's website, here's a link to it at [Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Philips-60W-Equivalent-Soft-White-SceneSwitch-A19-LED-Energy-Star-Light-Bulb-with-Warm-Glow-Effect-464883/300320213).

The [UK site](https://www.philips.co.uk/c-m-li/choose-a-bulb/sceneswitch) shows a 800 and 1600 lm version.

Another [SceneSwitch](https://www.usa.philips.com/c-m-li/choose-a-bulb/sceneswitch) version goes between 5000 K 100%, 2700 K 100% and 2200 K 10%. I actually have this model above my head right now, it works really well.

Comment: Actually this bulb gave me the idea of a self made "dimmer"

Answer (score 1):

Shop for something like this in your local hardware store:

[image: 3way canopy sws]

In the USA it is called a "three-way canopy switch" or "three-way lamp switch". (There's also a pull chain version but I have no picture.)

This kind of switch has four positions: (1) off; (2) black-to-red; (3) black-to-blue; (4) black-to-red-to-blue.

You connect your line hot to the switch black, the switch red to the hot side of the weaker bulb, and the switch blue to the hot side of the stronger bulb. (And, of course, your line neutral to the neutral of both bulbs.)

When you operate the switch it will cycle through (1) off; (2) weaker bulb on; (3) stronger bulb on; (4) both bulbs on. This gives a slightly finer control over the brightness than you asked for, but should generally satisfy your needs.

Comment: I love those, especially with 4-lamp fluorescent troffers with 2 ballasts: a 3-lamp and a 1-lamp.